# Auto set ASP.Net App_Sprites permissions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using the Image Optimization kit for ASP.Net and that needs the App Pool User to be able to write to the App_Sprites folder which I've already figured out how to do.

But when I'm publishing a new version of my system I need to manually change the folder permissions again. Is there a way to make the publishing system add the permissions?

I've searched a bit and couldn't find any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a root folder in your file system and grant required permissions for AppPool user to that folder. After that you can always publish your web application into the folder and you don't have to change permissions each time.